# Can I use Django's mail API in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using Django-nonrel for Google App Engine and I was wondering if it's possible to use Django's built-in mail API instead of GAE's mail API for sending mail. If it is, how do I do it?

Sorry if this seems like a noob question. I just started learning Django and GAE recently and I can't work out this problem that I have by myself.

Comment: Mail has a quota on App Engine, so i'll guess you're not able to use Django's mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, djangoappengine has a mail backend for GAE and it's enabled by default in your settings.py via "from djangoappengine.settings_base import *". You can take a look at the settings_base module to see all backends and default settings.

Comment: There is also a pluggable email backend that someone has created independent of djangoappengine, if you want a more lightweight solution. It works at the time of this post, according to testing in my dev environment. https://bitbucket.org/andialbrecht/appengine_emailbackends/overview